# Default read service Uri from AppSettings, after generating References.cs

Tags: service, web, appsettings

The problem relates to generate code when a web services is updated.
When I make update web referenc so it generated file References.cs. There is class of service, that has constructor, that reads settings about url from:

```
 this.Url = global :: <projectNamespace>. Properties.Settings.Default.MyServiceName;
```

After References.cs generate I manualy change it to:

```
this.Url System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServiceName"];
```

Is there any way to generate a default constructor, which will be read from the AppSettings?

For example with SchemaImporterExtension?